# Ошибка Missing required parameters for [Route: password.reset] [URI: {locale}/password/reset/{token}]

Tags: laravel

Ошибка возникает при попытке сбросить пароль. На тестовых файлах фреймворка всё работает хорошо. Но после изменения маршрутов возникает ошибка при попытке сбросить пароль. На формах авторизации и регистрации всё нормально.

Ниже ключевые листинги кода, где вносились изменения.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('index');
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'],
    'middleware' => 'setlocale'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('index');
    });
    Auth::routes();
});
```

**head**

```
<head>
...
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
...
</head>
```

**email.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts._main')
@section('content')
<section class="main_section">
    <div class="auth_wrapper">
        <div class="form_container">

            @if (session('status'))
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    {{ session('status') }}
                </div>
            @endif

            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.email', app()->getLocale()) }}" class="auth_login">

                @csrf

                <div class="auth_form_titles">
                    <h1 class="auth_form_title">@lang('forgot.caption')</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="auth_form_text">@lang('forgot.text')</div>

                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" 
                    @if($errors->has('email')) class="fields_error" @else class="fields" @endif 
                    placeholder="@lang('forgot.email_field')" title="@lang('forgot.email_field')" 
                    value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                    @error('email')
                        <span class="validation_error">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror

                <button type="submit" class="buttons button_login">@lang('forgot.button2')</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
@endsection
```

Если сейчас я нажму на кнопку «Отправить ссылку для сброса пароля», я получу сообщение об ошибке.

**Результат**

```
Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: password.reset] [URI: {locale}/password/reset/{token}].
```

---

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему. Понимаю так, что параметр {token} не передаётся, но как его передать в такой схеме, пока не знаю.

---

Данные для анализа этой ошибки: https://flareapp.io/share/lm2GgDPx#F61

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы ошибка не проявлялась при описанной схеме, достаточно сделать необязательным (?) префикс-параметр, а также перечислить языки регулярным выражением, как в листинге ниже:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale?}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '^ru|en$'],
    'middleware' => 'setlocale'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('index');
    });
    Auth::routes();
});
```